# Read Protocol Buffer Message and print Output from _pb2.py file in Python?

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers

I have multiple questions regarding Protocol Buffers. I have a _pb2.py file compiled from .proto. But then I am lost in terms of how to execute a message from a file and output desired results in Python. So far I have this in my Python code:

```
import ABC_pb2 as proto
import sys

message GroupManageFirstResponse
print results from this message...but I don't know how or where these results come from.
```

1. In ABC_pb2.py, I have a message that I would like to read. There are tons of messages. Following is the message in .proto I'd like to read and print output results via print:

   message GroupManageFirstResponse
   {
       optional ReportData total_data = 1;
       repeated ResultGroup results = 2;
       optional ADSResponse ads_res = 3;
       optional GmCalcStat stat_data = 4;
   }
2. My codebase is in C++ and the output is in binary and text file. This is what I don't understand. How is the data flowing in _pb2.py file? When I compile my C++ code, do I have to do anything with _pb2.py or just execute python because results are stored in binary?

Protocol Buffer is by far the hardest topic I've come across to understand. Almost there, though!

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow your question ... Protocol buffers are a serialization format (e.g. like JSON).  That format can be read and written using different languages.  The `.proto` file defines what a message looks like.  Different languages will work with it differently.  Python reads the `.proto` file and creates a `_pb2.py` file.  The `*_pb2.py` file is just a python module which defines classes that can be used to work with (serialize, deserialize) messages that have fields defined in the `.proto` file.

Comment: I got that part. I am just so used to JSON and XML :/. I'd be pretty happy if someone can demonstrate an example on how to read the *_pb2.py file and print output.

Comment: First you need to _get_ a message.  `msg = ABC_pb2.GroupManageFirstResponse.ParseFromString(data)` where `data` is the binary "wire format" of the serialized proto.  Now to print it you have a number of options.  One particularly nice option is `google.protobuf.text_format.MessageToString` -- Documentation is in [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/).